# Prevent certain functionality based on element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a button `.btn-1` that when clicked also triggers click on `.btn-2` I can't think of a way to do the following: when `.btn-2` is clicked also trigger click on `.btn-1` however in this case dismiss its functionality to trigger click on '.btn-2' to prevent infinite loop. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: There's a way. Using the `event` variable you can check if the `click` was triggered or really being clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass additional data to your handler using [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method:

```
$('.btn-2').on('click', function(event, skip) {
    // if the skip parameter is a truthy value
    // don't trigger the event
    if ( !skip ) {
       $('.btn-1').trigger('click', [true]);
    }
});

$('.btn-2').trigger('click', [true]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a boolean that switches:

```
var done=true;

$('.btn-1').click(function(){
    $('log').html($('log').html()+'bt1 pressed<br>')
    if(done){
        done=false;
        $('.btn-2').click()
    }
    done=true;
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2o3k5wet/

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way to do this:

```
$('.btn-1, .btn-2').on('click', function() {
    // do common stuff
    if ($(this).is('.btn-1')) {
        // do stuff only for 1
    }
    // do common stuff
});
```